# Hard limit of 10 running tasks per instance in AppEngine queue

Tags: google-app-engine, google-tasks

I have a GAE project, connected with an App Engine Queue (formerly 'push queue'), which should handle multiple tasks at once (target would be ~30 tasks per running instance). Somehow, I'm facing a hard limit of `10 * [COUNT OF RUNNING INSTANCES]` where I'm unable to get beyond. Since I tried several different settings and approaches, I hope for you guys shedding some light on this.

### TL;DR

GAE / queue setup for long-running tasks, written in PHP with Symfony, using backend instances (required), facing hard-limit of just 10 running tasks per instance. Any hint?

### The use-case

My original use-case involves the task handler to fetch data from an API, processes and stores it to BigQuery. In average, a single task handler is doing ~1.500 requests per minute. For scale, I'd wish to have something like 10 running instances (instance class `B4_1G`) with ~300 running tasks in parallel).

I created a small repository, available [here](https://github.com/winterstefan/gae.tasks.example/tree/master/apps/handler) on Github, where I simplified my use-case. For that, I took the plain example code from Google itself.
Please read the step-by-step guide for [how to reproduce](https://github.com/winterstefan/gae.tasks.example/tree/master/apps/handler#how-to-reproduce) my issue.

### Dependencies

The tasks are running rather long (~15 minutes each). Because of the limitation of GAE **Frontend** instances being cut at 10 minutes, I'm using **Backend instances** (also, for getting more memory capacity).

### The problem

Generally speaking, I'm unable to get more tasks running than the mentioned `10 * [COUNT OF RUNNING INSTANCES]`. I tried a lot (see below).

Running my original code in production, I get to about 30 % or memory usage per instance (if using `B4`). In other words: Speaking of resources, an instance would be capable of handling way more tasks, but it leaves up to 70% RAM unused.

Just 'something' restricts me to this hard limit of 10. I have no clue, where this limit could be. Maybe it's just one minor flag somewhere. :-(

### What I already tried

All of that, obviously, without the effect of getting over the limitation.

- Tried my example code in a brand new project (and even account)
- Contacted Google Cloud support (lots of communication, no real solution)

  - They do not believe in such a hard limit
  - Most viable information was: Need to define `max_concurrent_requests` for the GAE itself.
  - But that's not possible for `basic_scaling` thus for **Backend** instances.
  - Even with **Frontend** instances, I was unable to get over the limit.
- Tried running more instances and/or larger instance types (up to `B4_1G`)
- Tried **Frontend** instances (not my use-case for production, but just as test)
- Configured GAE with `entrypoint` and `--workers` flag (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#app_startup))

  - Tried queue `max_concurrent_requests: 15` with GAE `--workers=15` for just 1 running instance
- Tried both php72 and php73 environment
- Played around with all parameters of `app.yaml` and `queue.yaml`, according to the documentation

Since I'm really out of thoughts, I appreciate any type of hint where to look at. Maybe, you could even run & test my example code on your side.

*Thank you very much in advance.*

Comment: There are some [Qutas in IAM](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas), check these too.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I just double-checked and can confirm no quota exceeded right now.

E.g. `Cloud API - Requests per minute per region` is at about 2% quota